# Limiting Module Scope to Request (using Require, Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dependency-injection, scope

**Original Question**

*The current project I'm on is utilizing Express to manage HTTP requests.*

*The structure of the project is a bit complex, but without getting into too much detail, we have quite a few embedded `require` statements as-per-usual. The biggest issue we're running into is maintaining access to the request and response object. Aside from the below example, we're not quite sure what to do.*

```
 var MyModule = require('my-module.js')(request);
```

*Is it possible to inject the request into the child and its descendants' scopes? Without using a Global variable (due to overwriting it during concurrent requests), how can we make certain variables accessible to these descendants?*

**EDIT:**

I'm utilizing a pattern which requires module instances at different levels of scope (specifically Global, Session, and Request). `require` creates a single instance and simply returns that instance for subsequent requires. Within the confines of an entire section of code, it is necessary for arbitrary modules to be available at a session or request level because of the data they contain. In other words, while still using `require`, I need them to stay limited to a particular scope so that concurrent requests cannot access and modify them. Yet, I need to maintain the same basic functionality of `require`, just at a more limited scope.

Instead of a global scope (like now), they need to be instantiated each time a request comes in, and that instance should persist for each `require` related to that request.

The current solution was to utilize express' req to differentiate between multiple instances of the same module for retrieval purposes. If "this particular instance" was instantiated for "this particular request", that's the instance we need to make available when requireing. The biggest issue we're running into is that we're having trouble making the request available for the specific chain of requires in order to ensure the request is always known when requiring. Right now, we have no way to differentiate between which request instance we need to pull in while executing.

The only solution we can come up with is to find a way to recursively make the request available for that execution chain. But this is tedious and highly coupling. There doesn't seem to be a way to simply say "for this chain of execution, we'll create and then use all these instances".

**Example:**

```
# ModuleA, ModuleB, and ModuleC are at the request level.

ModuleA requires ModuleC and changes a value.

ModuleB later requires ModuleC and attempts to retrieve that value.
```

This works on the global scale of things, but we run into issues with concurrent requests. Because of this, if RequestA modifies ModuleC right before RequestB attempts to retrieve the value from ModuleC, then RequestB will be retrieve RequestA's value. This can be really nasty when we start to deal with sessions and the-like. We don't want Bob to be able to access George's instance of a User object.

What we want to avoid:

```
RequestA comes in -> ModuleA changes property value of ModuleC.foo to "bar"
RequestB comes in -> ModuleA changes property value of ModuleC.foo to "hello"
RequestA later -> ModuleB retrieves value of ModuleC.foo
RequestA expects -> ModuleC.foo = "bar"
Instead -> ModuleC.foo = "hello"
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem - are you trying to make the request object accessible throughout `my-module.js`? You should be able to create a namespaced (`this.request`) variable within your module that keeps track of the request. Then just pass that to any modules you call there and do the same thing.

If you want to retain access to an object across modules without explicitly passing said object, at some point you'll have to use the global space. That's just how JS works.

Full disclosure: I don't have in-depth experience building custom node modules, so I could be wrong here.

Comment: I think I may have just found my solution... `module.parent` [http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html]

Comment: @JordanForeman Indeed. What I was trying to avoid was having to pass it in to every single require statement every single time. Hopefully, but utilizing module.parent, I may be able to simply pass it to the initial `required` module, and then children can simply pull it from the parent if it is not explicitly being passed.

Comment: I didn't even know that existed! That will be much more efficient than storing a reference to the object in every module. Thanks for teaching *me* something today :)

Comment: @JordanForeman Neither did I! hahah

Comment: Can you give a better example of what you're trying to do? I'm not convinced this is the best solution. Edit: Requests should be handled through a series of middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon investigating it further, I found that [`module.parent`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) was exactly what I was looking for.

What I was trying to avoid was having to pass it in to every single require statement every single time. By utilizing `module.parent`, I was able to simply pass it to the initial required module, and then the children simple uses the parent to retrieve the request, if it is not explicitly being passed to it already. I can then access the `request` object without having to explicitly pass it down tens of levels.

Comment: When you talk about the `request` object you mean the **express** `req` right? I can't imagine a situation where you would need to do this. Can you provide a small example?

Comment: @Jordonias, I'm utilizing a pattern which requires module instances at different levels of scope (specifically Global, Session, and Request). `require` creates a single instance and simply returns that instance for subsequent `require`s. Within the confines of an entire section of code, it is necessary for arbitrary modules to be available at a session or request level because of the data they contain.

In other words, while still using `require`, I need them to stay limited to a particular scope so that concurrent requests cannot access and modify them.

Comment: @Jordonias The current solution was to utilize express' `req` to differentiate between multiple instances of the same module for retrieval purposes. If "this particular instance" was instantiated for "this particular request", that's the instance we need to make available when `require`ing. The biggest issue we're running into is that we're having trouble making the request available for the specific chain of requires in order to ensure the request is always known when requiring. Right now, we have no way to differentiate between which request instance we need to pull in while executing.

Comment: @Jordonias The only solution we can come up with is to find a way to recursively make the request available for that execution chain. But this is tedious and highly coupling. There doesn't seem to be a way to simply say "for this chain of execution, we'll create and then use all these instances".

Comment: so in some cases you are requiring a specific module(s) per each `request`, or for a specific `route`?

Comment: @Jordonias Per `request`. Certain modules need to function on a global level (the default behavior of `require`) and others need to be constructed and destructed each request. I've looked at simply making the `exports` a function that creates a new instance every time it is required, but I'm losing the ability to share the instance across other modules within that same request.

Comment: @Jordonias Example: ModuleA, ModuleB, and ModuleC are at the request level. ModuleA requires ModuleC and changes a value. ModuleB later requires ModuleC and attempts to retrieve that value. This works on the global scale of things, but we run into issues with concurrent requests. Because of this, if RequestA modifies ModuleC right before RequestB attempts to retrieve the value from ModuleC, then RequestB will be retrieve RequestA's value. This can be really nasty when we start to deal with sessions and the-like. We don't want Bob to be able to access George's instance of a User object.

Comment: @Jordonias I updated my question with the example in an easier-to-read format (hopefully, that is)

Comment: @Jordonias We're simply trying to avoid sharing module instances across concurrent requests. We want them to be isolated to a particular request.

Comment: I'm just wondering now if using modules is the right thing to be doing for this then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66050/discussion-between-swivelgames-and-jordonias).